# Ajax on submit button not working second time

Tags: forms, ajax

i am using ajax on my custom module (via example module)
the issue is ajax dependable select menu working correctly  and the submit button also giving result properly but submit button becomes not click able on 2nd time 
this snippet from my form

```
    $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => 'Search',
   '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_country_submit_driven_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'box',
    ),
 );
```

and here is the handler for submit button

```
function ajax_country_submit_driven_callback($form, $form_state) {

 $city = $form_state['values']['city'];

 if($city == -9){
   $parent_id = $form_state['values']['country'];
   $child_terms = taxonomy_get_children($parent_id);
   $city_data = array();
   $i=0;
   foreach ($child_terms as $term) {
    //$city_term =  $term->tid;
    $city_data[$i] = get_node($form ,$term->tid);
    $i++;
   }     
   return $city_data;
 }else{ 

   $element = get_node($form, $city);
   return $element; 
  }

}
```

get_node function

```
function get_node ($form, $city_tid){

$nodes[] = taxonomy_select_nodes($city_tid);

 foreach($nodes as $nid) { 
   $nodeid = $nid; 
 } 
 $i=0;
 foreach ($nodeid as $nid ) {
    $nodedata [$i]['nid']  =

 $nid; 
    $nodedata [$i]['title'] = get_node_title($nid);
    $nodedata[$i]['body'] = get_node_body($nid);
    $i++;
 }

 $element = $form['box'];



foreach ($nodedata as $node) {

$title = $node['title']; 
$nid = $node['nid'];
$body = $node['body'];
$element['#markup'] .="<h1>";
$element['#markup'] .=l(t('@title' , array('@title' => $title)) ,
'node/'.$nid , array('html' => TRUE));
$element['#markup'] .="</h1> <br>"; 
$element['#markup'] .="<p>". t('@body' , array('@body' => $body) );
$element['#markup'] .= "</p> <hr>";
 } 

  return $element;
}
```

Where its going wrong ?

Comment: Try with this. Add '&' in callback function like ajax_country_submit_driven_callback($form, &$form_state). Also add effect like fade with wrapper

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with these changes same result , nothing change

Comment: In second time, i think there is not displaying box wrapper. can you check html.

Comment: yes box wrapper remains there

Comment: I made in my custom module ajax callback, in that i am returning whole wrappe like $content = '<div class="commentInner" id="contentComments"><span>blah blah</span></div>';  And my element wrapper is like 'wrapper' => 'contentComments' and its working fine for me

Comment: its working fine for me too, but issue is submit button remains not clickable   on 2nd attempt , my wrapper also there not changed